# How to prevent only a single selected game from auto-updating on XBox One

Tags: xbox-one

I read that you can disable auto-updating of your games/apps on the XBox One by going to Settings > System > Updates and unchecking the box labeled "Keep my games & apps up to date.

But in my case I have only one game that I want to prevent from updating, basically to prevent issues with a multi-player game in which other platforms can't play without updating and updates for those platforms isn't always available right away when it is for the XBox.

All other games I want to keep on auto-update, because to not do so will interfere with other users of the XBox not having the updates they expect automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the method you mentioned, there is no way to stop individual games from automatically updating without stopping them all.